# Spring Boot Properties as Environment variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-environment

I have come across some behaviour which seems inconsistent in how spring boot handles environment variables in application properties files vs configuration property classes. I am unsure whether this is a bug in spring or an error in my understanding of what "ought" to happen.

I have

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
@Validated
public class ClientProperties {

    @NotBlank
    private String apiKey;

    @NotBlank
    private String uri;

}
```

In the `application.properties` file I have:

```
foo.baseUri=https://system.appspot.com
foo.uri=${foo.baseUri}/Valuation?apikey=${foo.apiKey}&bar={bar}
```

#### Setting Just FOO_APIKEY

If I run my app with:

```
export FOO_APIKEY=DEF
```

Then I get

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target class ClientProperties(apiKey=null, uri=https://system.appspot.com/Valuation?apikey=DEF&bar={bar}) failed:

    Property: foo.apiKey
    Value: null
    Reason: may not be empty
```

Note that in the URI the api key is set as expected as well as the base URI

#### Setting Just FOO_API_KEY

Next, if instead, I try to set just this property (remove the old env var):

```
export FOO_API_KEY=ABC
```

Then my app starts, but the values are not as expected. My logs show:

```
API Key: ABC.
URI Property: ${foo.baseUri}/Insurance?apikey=${foo.apiKey}&bar={bar}.
```

Note that now the base uri also disappeared as well as the API key being missing.

#### Setting Both Properties FOO_API_KEY and FOO_APIKEY

When I set both environment variables the app starts but the `apiKey` property of `ClientProperties` holds the value of the `FOO_APIKEY` export, where as the `uri` property of `ClientProperties` holds the value of the `FOO_API_KEY` export.

```
API KEY IS: ABC.
URI IS: https://system.appspot.com/Insurance?apikey=DEF&bar={bar}.
```

#### Notes

I actually don't need the value from `ClientProperties.apiKey`. It's only ever used in the app via the `ClientProperties.uri` which is already being resolved in `application.properties`. However, I specify the property so that I can have validation to ensure the value gets set. I could remove the value from my class and everything would be ok - expect then I lose my validation.

Spring boot version is: `1.5.10.RELEASE`

Comment: you can check this link: https://blog.indrek.io/articles/using-environment-variables-with-spring-boot/